# Website some content like table is not displayed once proxy is enabled

Tags: proxy, jmeter, blazemeter

I have set up a proxy in order to record the traffics.
However, some content on the website is not displayed.

Is that the web design issue?

the website is set up at local, multiple docker images consist of backend server, API and front end web-app.

[image]

The network result, I noticed no 200 OK returned but 502.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://0.0.0.0:8088/get_trained_models' from origin 'http://localhost:2000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only valid way of resolving this issue is asking the person who is responsible for your server configuration to add `localhost:8888` to [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

With regards to workarounds:

1. Try using a browser extension like [Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) or [Moesif Origin & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc) which make your application think that JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder host and port are valid origins
2. Use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) for recording the test

Comment: Just tried blazemeter, at the same time I downloaded the CORS plugin. on blazemeter, I use the recorder and see the webpage behave same, some content is empty.

Comment: Alternatively you can use your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) for recording, export the requests as [.HAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) and convert the .HAR file into JMeter .jmx script using [BlazeMeter Converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/)

Comment: yes i can only use HAR file then manual add it to jmeter. thanks!